# Building a SMS counting app for windows phone os

Tags: windows-phone-7, sms, windows-phone-8

Folks,I am planning to build an app to count the number of **sms's sent by an user** over a period of time.But I am not sure if WP OS SDK gives access to the depth of writing such an app.I am still very new to mobile development,and as Microsoft has **limited the access** to some API's (ex:language) in the windows phone OS,I was not sure if I can do so.
 On the contrary the application I want to build is kind of a basic feature that is in built in many basic phones.I need to get a start for app building,and may also come in handy on my personal phone! ;)
Anyone who has come across working on any related feature might help me with his experience.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone SDK does not allow developers to access the content of SMS messsages for privacy reasons (or count of those, for that matter).

Your best (and only) bet at the moment is let the user use [SmsComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394005%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and count the number of messages *potentially* sent from your app.

Comment: Thank you for the response Den!I am not sure how the count would breach the security? :P Anyways,I wanted it as I have limited no of sms' avalable per month and I end up sending more and paying more.But seems that it cannot be achieved as of now!My old nokia 1110 had it out of the box! I believe windows should have it that way! ;) :)

Comment: Please have a look at my other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351729/changing-profile-after-a-specific-time-interval-on-windows-phone-7-5)