# Changing profile after a specific time interval on windows phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

this question comes out a necessity that belongs to me! I want my profile to changed say everyday at 7:00 PM in the evening to **ringing+vibrate** from **silent**.I am not sure if it can be achieved as Microsoft has abstracted some features and prohibited access to them.

I would like to have it as an app,that allows me to set time for a particular period for a profile to stay active.Is it actually possible?Any experts having worked on this platform,please give your valuable suggestions as I am still a newbie in this town of mobile development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, the Windows Phone SDK does not allow you to change profiles from your application.

Now, since this is not your first question of this manner, I would highly recommend starting with [**MSDN documentation for Windows Phone development**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to see what is supported on the platform.

Comment: Definitely I will once I have some idea that the SDK supports ;)!!Thank you for feedback Den.It was of great help.